# Send the HttpSession through restTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, httpsession

How to send the HttpSession through the restTemplate to next `microservice` consider below exmple.

We have two miceoservices call  `A and B`. We are calling some restTemplate call to service B.

But in the Service B we are getting attributes through `httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("name");` this is the limitations in service B.

So how to pass the HttpSession to service B from A?

Comment: Resttemplate is deprecated, try to use webclient. Webclient supports both sync and async.

Comment: What deprecated ? Not correct I think.

Comment: Rest template will be deprecated soon

Comment: You cannot and shouldn't. The session is bound to an application/server. If you want to share it use something like Spring Session to put the session state in the database and just send the session identifier along so that each service can obtain the correct data.

Comment: Yes your point was correct but if we maintain any database then there many be some performance issues will come.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass the session through headers like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Your-Session-Header-Name", serialize(session));
ResponseEntity<UUID> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,new HttpEntity<Void>(headers), UUID.class);
```

And read session from headers at the server side

Comment: This is not the answer check my question correctly.